# How do I use a filter for an element that is three levels deep

Tags: angular, filter

I have a structure like this returned from a service call:

```
var office = [
  {
    "Name": "office 1",
    "address": [
      {
        "address1": "addres line 1",
        "LocationOptions": [
          {
            "WheelChairAccessible": "Yes",
        "OpenToPublic": "Open"
         }
        ]
      },
    {
      "address1": "addres line 1",
      "LocationOptions": [
        {
          "WheelChairAccessible": "No",
      "OpenToPublic": "Closed"
        }
      ]
     },
    ]
   },
     "Name": "office 2",
     "address": [
       {
         "address1": "addres line 1",
         "LocationOptions": [
       {
              "WheelChairAccessible": "No",
          "OpenToPublic": "Closed"
           }
     ]
        }
     ]
   }
];
```

I have been trying to apply the filter so that I can make on service call to get the data back in the format I am looking for, but have been unable to have the filter work to multiple levels.

I have tried the following to break down the to where I want to filter the data I am looking for:

```
this.fileteraddress = this.ds.serviceCall(detailParameters)
      .pipe( 
        filter(res => 
          res.Address.map( res => 
            res2.LocationOptions.filter( res3 =>
              res3.OpenToPublic != "Open")
          ) 
        )
      .subscribe (res =>
        this.fileteraddress = res
      );
```

I have also tried to use the map function, but was not able to have the filters applied correctly.

I would like to have the filter work so I get the data back like this:

```
var Open Offices = [
  {
    "Name": "office 1",
    "address": [
      {
        "address1": "addres line 1",
    "LocationOptions": [
           {
        "WheelChairAccessible": "Yes",
            "OpenToPublic": "Open"
       }
     ]
      }
    ]
  }    
];
```

Comment: LocationOptions is an array, can one address have multiple location options?

Comment: Yes, each address can have multiple Location Options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting your response as an array.

```
this.ds.serviceCall(detailParameters).pipe(
   map(t=> 
   t.filter((t: any)=> {    
    return t.address.filter((a:any) => {
      return a.LocationOptions.filter((loc:any) => {
        return loc.OpenToPublic === 'Open';
      }).length > 0;
    }).length > 0;

    return false;
  }
  ))).subscribe(t=> this.result = t);
}
```

Here is the stackblitz, if you want to try this out. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xecicg

Comment: I was able to get see this work in the stackblitz, however when I try it in my code I am an error t.filter is not a function.

I have the is there something I need to to for the declaration of the call for the variable?